# Why can't the google JWT token be decoded by jwt.io

Tags: azure, google-api, jwt, google-oauth, postman

I have Google authentication enabled in an Azure App Service .NET Core application, and I am trying to generate an access token using Postman: [image]

An `access token` and an `id_token` get successfully generated, but when I input the `access token` into [jwt.io](http://jwt.io), I see gibberish back:
[image]

**I am new to google auth as well as JWT in general, so my expectation may be totally invalid, but shouldn't I be able to decode the token on [jwt.io](http://jwt.io)?**

Comment: [RFC6749 section 1.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.4): `An access token is a string representing an authorization issued to the client.  **The string is usually opaque to the client**`

Answer (score 29):

The access token is not a JWT. The id_token is a JWT and you should be able to decode it using jwt.io.

The difference is connected to the difference between OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect.

The access token is used to make additional requests to Google API:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi

The id_token already holds the information for the authenticating user:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you pasted only two parts of the token in the Encoded area, I see only 1 dot in the string. In the sample given by jwt.io there is 2 dots in it that separates it to 3 parts.

Comment: After digging some more, it seems that maybe I am pasting the wrong part. As I mentioned, I received an `access token` and an `id token`. I pasted the `access token`, but it seems that only the `id token` is the JWT component. But I am confused what the difference is.

Comment: I am not familiar with Postman but a JWT always contains three parts, separated with a dot. The first is the header, the second is the payload data. The third is a signature that is usually encrypted.