# Why do I get "Token is not revocable." from Google Auth API on online access token revocation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

When trying to revoke "online" access type access token from Google's https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth endpoint I get different responses, from two separate users:

a. one user, when calling GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=ONLINE_ACCESS_TOKEN, gets a 200 status code response;

b. another user, when calling the same endpoint, from the same Chrome extension, gets a 400 status code response, with the payload:

```
{
     error: "invalid_request",
     error_description: "Token is not revocable."
}
```

I've tested both tokens by calling https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?access_token=ONLINE_ACCESS_TOKEN, and both are of the same type(online) and still valid(not expired).

What could cause this issue/error message on one side, and not on the other?

Comment: I wonder if they are both access tokens.  Have you tried to decrypt them both?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes. Requesting tokeninfo using the URL from above renders a response with the same shape(both of online access_type, both with verified_email, both with valid expires_in values).

Comment: Try putting them both though https://jwt.io/

Comment: @DaImTo access_token is not a standard JWT, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623656/why-cant-the-google-jwt-token-be-decoded-by-jwt-io.