# Next Auth google OAuth with custom backend's access token and refresh token

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, nestjs, next-auth

I have a NestJS backend that exposes the following API:

```
   @Post('sign-in-with-google-account')
   async signInWithGoogleAccount(
     @Body body: { idToken: string }, 
     @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response
   ) {
     const user = await getUserFromGoogleIdToken(body.idToken)
     const tokens = await generateAccessAndRefreshTokensForUser(user)

     response.cookie('refreshToken', tokens.refreshToken, {
         httpOnly: true,
         expires: new Date(tokenExpirationDate),
         secure: true,
         sameSite: 'none'
     })

     return { accessToken: tokens.accessToken }
   }
```

It receives id token from google oauth, finds the user in the DB and signs a JWT access token and refresh token. The refresh token is stored as `httpOnly` cookie and the access token is returned.

Now in my next.js app configured with `next-auth` I have the following:

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

...
providers: [
  GoogleProvider({
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
  })
]
...
```

The problem is that `next-auth` generates its own tokens. But I want `next-auth` to use my own access and refresh tokens from the NestJS backend, how can I do that?

Also, In NestJS I have a API to refresh the access token like so:

```
@Get('refresh-access-token')
async refreshAccessToken(@Req() request: Request) {
  const accessToken = await getNewAccessTokenFromRefreshToken(request.cookies.refreshToken)
  return { accessToken } 
}
```

How can I tell `next-auth` to refresh the access token using `refresh-access-token` API every 10 minutes (the access token expiration date)?

Comment: Have you got the answer for this question? I'm also stuck in same scenario. I want to use the `next-auth` to use the tokens generated by my custom backend. Not the one created by next-auth itself. I want to integrate `Google Login` and `Credentials Provider`

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is 0 documentation about this. I guess next-auth and next.js in general is more about doing NOTHING custom, but to pay for third party services like auth0 or clerk. I gave up on next.js and decided to use good old react + vite

Comment: Looking into this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359472/how-can-i-verify-a-google-authentication-api-access-token

Comment: did u find any solution to this question im stuck too in this senario?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save the previous time to local storage and then compare it with current time to call the api. You can use `moment.unix()` or `moment.diff()` to do this.